# How to make QtWebEngine obey macOS auto-scrollbar setting

Tags: macos, qt5, qtwebengine

**QtWebEngine** (tried 5.9.2, 5.9.3, 5.9.10) does not obey macOS scrollbar setting to auto-show scrollbars. The scroll-indicator is always visible.  We're seeing it in a C++ Qt app, but happen elsewhere, such as in the Qt sample **quicknanobrowser**. Non-Qt Chromium based apps such as Electron (and Chrome itself) behave correctly.

Anybody found a way to work around this with Qt-supplied binaries?

Quicknanobrowser example:
[image: scrollbar problem with Qt example program]
And in our product where it's particular ugly:
[image: example in our product]

I opened a Qt issue: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-65745

More detail on expected behavior: macOS system preference **Show scroll bars** is set to **Automatically based on mouse or trackpad**: a scrollable control should hide the scrollbar until you begin scrolling with trackpad or a mouse with scrolling capability. Then it will show a scroll-indicator, and if you mouse over that it turns into a scrollbar.